# Add Text Panel in Matplotlib Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to add some kind of panel next to a plot where only text can be written.

Here is a picture describing what I want to do.

[image: Plot and panel]

As in the picture, I also want to change the color, weight and style of the text.

I've tried using a `matplotlib.widgets.Textbox` but it didn't work.
Also tried to add a subplot, set the axis off and write but don't know how to change the style of the different part of my Panel.

I want to use only matplotlib for that if possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you could implement this chart.
More information about available text properties you can find [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x):
    return (x**2)*exp(-(x**2))
def f3(x):
    return (x**4)*exp(-(x**2))


x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.05)
f2 = np.vectorize(f)
f4 = np.vectorize(f3)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,7))
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots', fontsize=20)
ax1.plot(x, f2(x), 'red', label='(t^2)*exp(-(t^2))')
ax1.plot(x, f4(x), 'darkblue', linestyle='dotted', linewidth='4', label='(t^4)*exp(-(t^2))')


ax1.set(title="2 lines chart", xlabel="t", ylabel="y")
ax1.legend(loc="upper right")


# Set both x- and y-axis limits to [0, 10] instead of default [0, 1]


ax2.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')

ax2.text(0.5, 9, 'Topic 1', weight='bold', fontsize=15,
         bbox={'facecolor': 'red', 'alpha': 0.3, 'pad': 10})
ax2.text(0.5, 7.5, '- Bullet pont 1\n- Bullet point 2', fontsize=12 )


ax2.text(0.5, 5.5, 'Topic 2', weight='bold', fontsize=15,)
ax2.text(0.5, 4.5, '- Bullet pont 1\n- Bullet point 2', fontsize=12 )

ax2.text(2, 3, r'a function to plot: $t^2*exp(-t^2)$', fontsize=12)

ax2.text(0.5, 2, "colored text", fontsize=12, color='darkblue')




plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was expecting a simplier way to do it. Like the existence of another kind of subplot Or a panel that can be added if asked.
I'm going to use your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you dont need to change text weight, switching from bold to normal and use for example CAPs for topic , you can do it as one subplot.